# Arithmetic operator wont register when compiling

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Just started kearning c#, and I have been having some trouble when running the console application. For some reason, when I run the console application, it runs the sayHello method, but won't run the Arithmetic method.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
using System;

class Mainclass {

public static void sayHello(string username, string servername)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Could you please enter your name : ");

    username = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Hello " + username + "," + " my name is " + servername + ".");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static float Arithmetic (float value)
{


    return value * value;
}




static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, Welcome to the football scout app.");

    sayHello((Console.ReadLine()), "Mr. Scout");

    Arithmetic(200);

}
```

Comment: Its running just fine, you're just not doing anything with it. Try `Console.WriteLine(Arithmetic(200));` to print the returned value in the `Console`

Comment: How do you know it isn't executing that method? You're not producing any output from it, or after you've called it. Try placing a breakpoint inside the Arithmetic method and run through the debugger.

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys!

Answer (score 3):

It certainly *does* run the method, you just have not implemented any output.

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, Welcome to the football scout app.");

    sayHello((Console.ReadLine()), "Mr. Scout");

    Console.WriteLine("200 squared equals " + Arithmetic(200).ToString());
}
```